# Missing a step to get value to loop

Tags: javascript, cloudkit

I have this section of js code that I am having an issue with. If I bind-data in my html to fields.timeStamp.value I get the correct values to display in each row on the web page. How ever if I data-bind to conTime1 I get a repeat of the first value instead of it converting each lines value.

**JavaScript**

```
records.forEach(function (record){
        var fields = record.fields;
        var timeStamp = fields['timeStamp'].value
        var conTime = new Date(timeStamp)
        conTime1 = conTime.toString();

    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="two columns">
  <p><span data-bind="text: fields.timeStamp.value"></span></p>
</div>
<div class="four columns">
  <p><span data-bind="text: conTime1"></span></p>
</div>
```

I am sure it some thing simple that I am missing.

Comment: I'm guessing `record.conTime1 = conTime.toString();` ?

Comment: @ChrisG That worked!!! Submit as an answer so you can get more credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the record's `conTime1`, like this:

```
record.conTime1 = conTime.toString();
```